# Permissions prevent creating new virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, permissions, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I get an error when I try to create a new virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper. Here's the command I'm trying:

```
mkvirtualenv -a . -i Flask ~/.virtualenvs/dcc-admin/
```

Here's the output:

```
New python executable in /Users/raddevon/.virtualenvs/dcc-admin/bin/python
Installing setuptools......
  Complete output from command /Users/raddevon/.vir...dcc-admin/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
  Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Removing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: Permission denied
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1091, in create_environment
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 611, in install_setuptools
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 583, in _install_req
    cwd=cwd)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1057, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/raddevon/.vir...dcc-admin/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /Library/Python/2.7/...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
```

I thought I could get around this with `sudo`, but that gives me `sudo: mkvirtualenv: command not found`.

I've checked my permissions on the file causing the error, and my user appears to have read and write permissions.

[image: Effective permission on the file in question for my user account]

I'm not sure where to go from here. `mkvirtualenv` should be able to delete that file since I have the delete permission for it. Alternately, sudo should be able to run `mkvirtualenv`. Someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

**Update:** I figured out part of this problem. virtualenvwrapper was trying to run the Python commands through a different install of the Python interpreter than the one I wanted. I used the `-p` switch to specify the correct interpreter, and that worked.

I read up on this, and, apparently, it should be using the same interpreter that would be the default in my shell, but this is not the case. The interpreter used as the default by the shell is `/usr/local/bin/python` but virtualenvwrapper is trying to run through `/Library/Python/...` I'm still unsure why this is the case. `/usr/local/bin` is the last python path defined in my .zshrc.

Answer (score 0):

I currently found a workaround 
`virtualenv env -p /usr/local/bin/python`